# creating a profile to add to a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to have the ability to allow the user to fill out a profile, almost like the notes app and then when they are done it adds it to the UITableViewCell and displays certain parts of what they filled out on the Cell..Then they can obviously repeat this action..

I am not sure where to look for a tutorial on this or what this may be called, anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Though the concept is pretty simple, there can be quite a bit of plumbing involved.  Without knowing specifics, I would suggest checking out some objective c books at your local bookstore.  They organize these concepts pretty well and its in one spot.  Googling the web might be a bit difficult at first, but look into  UITableViewDelegate as well as UITableViewDatasource.  These contain methods which may be implemented to populate your table.  As for the form, check into interface builder.

Comment: What specifically, do you need help with? How to put data from text field's into an array? How to use an array to populate a table view? I would suggest reading Apple's "Table View Programming Guide for iOS".

Comment: @rdelmar I guess Im not sure on the lingo of it, ironically I know how to code to a certain extent..I want to have a UILabel and a UIImage populate onto a UITableViewCell into a list after someone goes in and fills out a profile of something..if that makes sense

Comment: You need to implement textFieldDidEndEditing, and in that method put the text of the text field into whatever data source you use to populate the table  view (an array or array of dictionaries probably), then call reloadData on the table view. It's hard to give you more specific advice without knowing how you want the work flow to go.

Comment: hey well I guess its a start! thanks for taking the time to help me out ill check up on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Five simple steps :

1)Design how form is gonna look like and your tableview.

2)Make the form using a sample [UIviewcontroller](http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/ios/tutorial_iosdev/viewcontroller/) layout your components using xib or 
[storyboard](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

3) Embed your UIViewcontroller designed in step 2 into a [UINavigationViewController](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/)
This helps you to transition from your form to UITableView

4) Design your [UITableViewController](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/) and put a back button on UINavigationBar to allow user to go to previous view controller.

5) Connect UIViewController to UITableViewController

```
-(void)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender{

    UITableViewController *tvc = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"your view controller name"];

   // pass data to UITableViewController 
   tvc.userdata = self.userdata;

   [self.navigationController pushviewController:tvc];

}
```

Comment: whoa thats pretty dead on to what I was looking for..thank you!